# BottomNavigation BadgeDrawable set displayed number in a specific Locale irrespective of selected one

Tags: android, localization, material-components-android, badge, android-bottomnavigationview

The project supports RTL; Arabic in particular.
The requirement is that all numbers must appear in English format even when language is selected as Arabic Locale, the way we achieve it everywhere is usually the following code in case of TextViews:

```
TextView t = findViewById(R.id.sampleTV);
t.setText(String.format("123",Locale.US));
```

Here 123 would be shown as "123" since we formatted it in US locale quite hardcoded-ly not "١٢٣"

I want to achieve the same for the Badge Notifications provided by Android Material Component's Bottom Navigation, here is what I've tried:

```
if(navigation!=null) {  
  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);

  BadgeDrawable badgeDrawable = navigation.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.nav_account);
  if (badgeDrawable != null) {
      if((counterNoti + counter + counterRoom) <= 0) {
      badgeDrawable.setVisible(false);
      badgeDrawable.clearNumber();
  }
  else
      {
      int x = counterNoti + counter + counterRoom;
      nf.format(x);
      badgeDrawable.setVisible(true);
      badgeDrawable.setNumber(x);
  }
}

(where navigation is reference to my BottomNavigation!)
```

Yet even with this the number is shown in Arabic not like setText's case. Is there a way to achieve this or I need an alternative?

Appreciate your input and time! Thanks.

Comment: do you find any good solution bro...?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, changing the local for the current JVM instance by calling the following function in onCreate

```
private fun numbersFormat() {
    val locale = Locale.ENGLISH
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
}
```

Comment: See that's the thing. Our requirement is that the LOCALE would be ARABIC but the numbers remain English everywhere (as to omit Arabic numeric characters i.e ١٢٣).
Also utilizing Android's Single Activity Architecture, so our onCreate() one activity detects locale which we've selected and loads that one (and that's usually AR).

So, like I've stated on the initial question, in case of string setting I specifically use the String.format(string,Locale.US); method to get the desired effect, wanted to do the same at Material Bottom Navigation.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know your struggle here but i don't think its possible to change the locale just for the string itself in the badge of the material design library alone because the method that sets the text on the BadgeDrawable is private, generally speaking tho i don't think its a good idea to force your strings into a specific local, i mean if the user has set their numbers to a specific local in android settings then they want it to be that way and they probably use it across all apps in their phone already.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change badge numeric text locale in a simple way. My decision was to create custom badge via xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_badge"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_badge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="21dp"
    android:minHeight="21dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Typography.BadgeCounter"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    tools:text="999+" />
```

Inflate layout in your fragment and set TextView's text liek this:

```
txtCounter.text = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format(counter)
```